# How come JsonConvert.DeserializeObject in WP8 app works, ni WP8 ScheduledTask doesn't

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8, json.net, background-process

I got a REST service running in AWS which returns some information. When I access the service from within my app, all works well. When I use the exact same code in a scheduledtask, it doesn't.
The weird thing is, there is no error, no exception, no hint as to what is going on other than that when stepping through the code in Visual Studio, when hitting F10 on the line where `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` is called it doesn't step over the line executing it, but it is the same as hitting F5.

My code is:

```
private void infoRetrieval_DownloadCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null)
    {
        string response = e.Result;
        if (response != null)
        {
            try
            {
                CDateTime info = null;
                CJsonDateTime r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CJsonDateTime>(response);
                info = new CDateTime(r);    

                if (info != null)
                {
                     // Indicate that there is a new info
                }
            } 
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                // The exception can't be handled in a meaningful way, so it's ignored.
            }
       }
    }
}
```

The code that does the actual call to the webservice looks like this, and it is also the exact same code I use both in my App and in my agent as part of the OnInvoke method:

```
infoRetrievalClient = new WebClient();
infoRetrievalClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(infoRetrieval_DownloadCompleted);
infoRetrievalClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(<the URI to the webservice>));
```

Note that I am using the exact same code in my App as well as my ScheduledTaskAgent. Furthermore, I checked and the string retrieved in both cases is exact the same. Problem here is just that I can't parse the JSON and use the data.

The call to NotifyComplete is in the OnInvoke.

Any help is highly appreciated as I'm currently stuck.

Iwan

Comment: when and where do you call NotifyComplete() in the scheduled task?

Comment: The OnInvoke is where I do the request and it registers in the WebClient de callback to the "completed" event.
I updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it, it turned out that Igor's question put me on the right track. I moved the NotifyComplete to the callback of the web-request and now it is all processing nicely.

Thanks Igor.

Iwan